# Algorithms: Square root optimization

Tags: python, algorithm

**Question:**
    Implement `int sqrt(int x)`.
    Compute and return the square root of `x`.
    Example:
        `sqrt(3) = 1`
        `sqrt(4) = 2`
        `sqrt(5) = 2`
        `sqrt(10) = 3`

My code:

```
def sqrt(self, x):
        # write your code here
        if x == 0:
            return x
        start = 1
        end = x
        while start + 1 < end:
            mid = (end - start)/2
            if mid*mid == x:
                return mid
            if mid*mid < x:
                start = mid
            else:
                end = mid
        if end*end <= x:
            return end
        return start
```

Error Hint:

Your code ran too much time than we expected. Check your time complexity. Time limit exceeded usually caused by infinite loop if your time complexity is the best.

My question: How to improve it?

Comment: free hint: don't compute `mid*mid` twice. Use a variable.

Comment: also use `(end - start)//2` (integer division) for python 3

Comment: your algorithm is broken. It has an infinite loop

Comment: another free hint: run the code yourself first

Answer (score 1):

The main error in your code was to use `mid = (end-start)//2` instead of  `mid = (end+start)//2` to compute the mid-range value. This created the infinite loop. So you were not very far from the solution :

```
def sqrt(x):
    if x == 0:
        return x
    start = 1
    end = x
    while start+1 < end:
        mid = (end + start) // 2
        delta = mid*mid - x
        if delta < 0:
            start = mid
        elif delta > 0:
            end = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return start

for x in (2, 5, 9, 13, 18, 24, 27):
    print("sqrt(%s) ~= %s" % (x, sqrt(x)))
```

which produces the following output :

```
sqrt(2) ~= 1
sqrt(5) ~= 2
sqrt(9) ~= 3
sqrt(13) ~= 3
sqrt(18) ~= 4
sqrt(24) ~= 4
sqrt(27) ~= 5
```

Comment: This ought to be good enough to pass the test, but it can be made faster.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Do you mean something like Babylonian method, false position, ..., or do you talk aqbout the implementation?

Comment: I meant mainly the initial guess. Now it's the midpoint. I got it a little faster by counting the number of bits in x, and by shifting by half the amount getting a very crude approximation of the square root.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishake gupta, thanks, it works. there is a small mistakes:

```
  def sqrt(self, x):
        # write your code here
        if x == 0 or x == 1:
            return x
        i = 1
        result = 1
        while result <= x:
            if result == x:
                return i
            i += 1
            result = i*i
        return i-1
```

Comment: This, on the other hand, may be too slow.